# Running a javascript inside the head tag in Selenium RC

Tags: javascript, selenium-rc

I want to run a javascript snippet inside the `<head>` tag. Is that possible to do that in Selenium RC+Java?

I understood that if I use getEval or runScript that will insert the code inside the HTML body.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that by the time Selenium is able to interact with the page, it has already been loaded, which means you wouldn't be able to add something to the <head> element.

You could use runScript to dynamically add a script tag to the head element using DOM manipulation techniques but this is probably not what you're after either...